# Windows Form C# Graph Axes Label on both X & Y axes

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

Can anyone please tell me how to write the labels on the x-y-axes on the graph? The ones that say "Time(s)" & "Speed (m/s)".

I am using `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart`. There should be a simple property somewhere which I am missing or is it something more complicated?

[image: graph with labeled axes]

Comment: Have you tried looking into the [Chart Title](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart.titles.aspx) object.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I found the Axis Title property useful (check the selected answer)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I am using the charts control on the web and setting the X and Y axis titles are done in the following way.

I assume the API would be the same for winforms.

```
var chartArea = new ChartArea("MyChart");
...
chartArea.AxisX.Title = "Times(s)";
chartArea.AxisY.Title = "Speed (m/s)";
```

Comment: Philip, I couldn't `edit` your answer but I guess the third line in your snippet should be `chartArea.AxisX.Title = "Times(s)";`

Comment: How to edit the Axis Labels?

Answer (score 2):

None of the solutions worked for me. I used the following code which helped me to add Axis title on windows form chart. I am adding a couple of useful properties so anyone who is working on it can have an idea how to use it. I searched a lot to find out all those properties. There are very few examples of this types.

```
chartESTOr.Titles.Add("Est OR Date " + " (" + Year + ")").Font = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold); // Chart Title
chartESTOr.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Title = "Month";  // Chart X Axis Title
chartESTOr.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.TitleAlignment = StringAlignment.Center; // Chart X axis Text Alignment 
chartESTOr.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.TextOrientation = TextOrientation.Rotated270; // Chart X Axis Text Orientation 
chartESTOr.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.TitleFont = new Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Bold); // Chart X axis Title Font
chartESTOr.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Interval = 1; // Chart X Axis Interval
chartESTOr.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Title = "Quote Value (USD)"; // Chart Y Axis Title 
chartESTOr.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.TitleAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;  // Chart Y axis Text Alignment 
chartESTOr.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.TextOrientation = TextOrientation.Horizontal; // Chart Y Axis Text Orientation
chartESTOr.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.TitleFont = new Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Bold); // Chart Y axis Title Font
chartESTOr.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "{0:0,}K"; // Chart Y Axis lable format
```